# How can I ignore irrelevant mergeinfo changes when scanning a log?

Tags: c#, sharpsvn, mergeinfo

Recently my scan for relevant changes has been including mergeinfo changes that are not relevant and I would like to ignore these revisions where the changes in the log item do not alter any items in the folder which I am iterating.

I can iterate through the svnChangeItems and check for the mergeinfo property but how do I tell if a ChangeItem was made to a file which was committed to the folder whose log items I am scanning. Similar to hide unrelated change paths except if I were to check this option in the log viewer It would not show some relevant revisions which include changes before the folder I was scanning moved. Any ideas?

Comment: On the command line, one can use `svn diff --summarize -r X:Y | grep -v "^ "` (summarize hides actual diffs, and the grep filters out property modifications marked with "M" in the second column). Unfortunately not possible with `svn log` (where you'd expect it; there is an [inactive branch in subversion](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/branches/ignore-mergeinfo/BRANCH-README) for that feature).